# Proper iframe focus for accessibility purposes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, accessibility

I'm using iframe to show login page in another page. Here is how my code looks like

```
codeblock 1
codeblock 2
<iframe>
   codeblock 3
   codeblock 4
</iframe>
codeblock 5
```

When I'm testing it on screen reader for accessibility, the screenreader reads codeblock 1 and 2, and then instead of going into iframe or codeblock 5 it goes back to the start of the page.

How can I move it into iframe after codeblock 2 and move focus out of iframe after reading codeblock 4?

I know iframes are notorious, but is there any solution available to problem like this?

Comment: Your iframe should have a 'src' attribute with the location of the form page. iframes are intended to load in an external resource into your page using this attribute. If you included a src attribute but omitted it here, could you give us more information, such as the screen reader you're using to test?